# Canon Rebel camera

Tags: wine, uninstall, canon, camera

I installed software for Canon camera in wine and it didn't work well. I went to wine uninstaller and removed some utilities but cant get them all out need to remove them and a suggestion on a way to get a canon software for Linux or something that will work well

Answer (score 0):

#### Deleting software installed with Wine

If you installed the software in a separate Wine prefix as recommended, you can simply delete the prefix root directory and create a new one. Wine isn't really made to cleanly delete software, because it's easier to just create new prefixes.

If you don't know how or don't want to manage your Wine prefixes manually, use a GUI front-end like PlayOnLinux.

#### Using your digital camera with Ubuntu Linux

You most probably don't need the Windows software to use the camera. They usually use standard USB mass storage drivers and the tools shipped with the camera are just crappy image editors and photo collection managers. There are far superior tools in the Ubuntu repositories (e. g. GIMP, Pinta, shotwell) and you may even get along with the file manager, if you just need to view or copy/move the pictures.

Comment: I want ed to use the photo editing software that came with the camera but didn't work I have a few that I downloaded for linux but thy don't do the type of editing I like or are hard to figure out

Comment: Pinta, built after its role model Paint.NET, is simple to use and can do basic photo editing. GIMP is very powerful with many functions but also more difficult to use. It has however a big community and good documentation.